# Jupyter-notebook numpy.core.umath failed to import

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

Jupyter notebook raised "numpy.core.umath failed to import" error when I imported tensorflow.But, It can be imported correctly in other situation,such as CMD and pycharm.

tf2 is a conda virtual env

I used ipykernel mapping conda virtual env to jupyter notebook.

```py
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name tf2 --display-name tf2
```

numpy                1.16.4
tensorflow           2.0.0a0 
tensorflow-gpu       2.0.0a0 
tensorlayer          2.1.0

I tried to change numpy version to 1.16.3+mkl,the problem still existence.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

### here is the error info

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you activated the conda environment before starting Jupyter? Or are you relying on the Anaconda kernel provider, which finds kernels in different environments and activates the environment when starting the kernel?

If neither, try one of those.

Comment: I I confused two virtual envs, base and tf2. I just installed ipykernel and mapped virtual env tf2 to jupyter notebook at base, then run jupyter notebook at base, It may cause the problem.NOW, I install ipykernel and map the virtual env at tf2,  then Active tf2 and run jupyter notebook, It run successfully.Thanks for you advice.